# Difference between i++ and ++i in a for loop

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Incrementing in C++ -  When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

What is the difference between

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
//...do something
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
{
//...do something
}
```

?

Comment: Many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x

Answer (score 5):

Nothing at all.  The increment is a lone statement, so whether it is pre-incremented or post-incremented doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It only matters if the optimizer isn't clever enough to realize that it can do ++i even though you specified i++.  (Which is not very likely in modern compilers.)

You can recognize really old programmers because they always use ++i unless they need to use i++, because once apon a time compilers were a lot less clever.

Comment: Not really to do with age, more to do with exposure to non-trivial iterators in C++.

Comment: I must be a really old programmer then, because I like to write my code so the results are intentional, not accidental.

Answer (score 1):

The post- and pre- increment operators matter mainly if you care about the value of some variable in a compound statement.  Standalone increment statements, as the third clause of the for loop is, aren't impacted by your choice of pre or post.

`int j = i++;` and `int j = ++i;` are very different.  Do you want the current value of `i` or do you want the incremented value of `i`?  In the for loop example, you don't care so long as you increment.