# difference between ++i and i++ in for loop

Tags: post-increment, pre-increment

I understand well how postfix and prefix increments/decrements work. But my question is, in a for loop, which is more efficient or faster, and which is more commonly used and why?

Prefix?

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {...}
```

Or postfix?

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {...}
```

Comment: should not make a difference!

Comment: @Saket not true in general, but true for ints in this case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between i++ and ++i in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391141/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: possible duplicate of [i++ less efficient than ++i, how to show this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116735/i-less-efficient-than-i-how-to-show-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, none is actually more efficient than the other. I would expect `++i` to be more commonly used, because that's what would be more efficient for other kinds of iterations, like iterator objects.

Comment: Why does it only matter when iterator or object are in use?

Answer (score 1):

For `int`s in this context there is no difference -- the compiler will emit the same code under most optimization levels (I'd venture to say even in the case of no optimization).

In other contexts, like with C++ class instances, there is some difference.

Answer (score 0):

Either works, and one is not more efficient or faster than the other in this case. It's common for people to use ++1, maybe because that is what was used in K&R and other influential books.

Comment: There is no reason that `++i` (especially in a statement context) needs to create any more "local copies" that `i++` does.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, choosing prefix or postfix in a for loop depends on the language itself. In c++ prefix is more efficient and consistent. Because in the prefix type, compiler does not need to copy of unincremented value. Besides your value must not be an integer, if your value is an object than this prefix type is more powerful.