# To write a function that prints each element of a STL vector despite the type

Tags: c++, stl

I tried with this piece of code but it didn't work

```
template <class T>
void display(vector<T> vec)
{
  vector<T>::iterator MyIter;
  for(MyIter=vec.begin();MyIter!=vec.end();MyIter++)
    cout<<*MyIter<<" ";
  cout<<endl;
}
```

I mean if there's a way of avoid making a function for each type T (int, char, string). I'm using only builtin types for T.

This is the error message when I compile the program

```
10 C:\Documents and Settings\ASPIRE\Desktop\perms.cpp expected `;' before "MyIter"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `typename` infront of the variable definition `MyIter` i.e. it should be `typename  vector<T>::iterator MyIter;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear on how this code did not work?

It relies on the existence of T::operator<< - if that is not present for any instantiating type/class T that you use in your code, the code will not compile.  For builtin types this code would work OK.  If you are using this for vector of your own types then you would have to implement operator<< for each for this to work.

btw use `++MyIter`, it's more efficient.

Comment: why is ++Myiter more efficient?

Comment: Because the other form has to do an extra copy constructor call in order to return the correct value.  Check the prefix and postfix increment declarations in your <vector> header file.  See also duffymo's response here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x

Comment: btw, passing the vector in by value is expensive. Rather use `const vector<T> & vec`.