# How does this code work?

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment

I am looking at c++ for dummies and found this code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int nextStudentId = 1000; // first legal Student ID
class StudentId
{
public:
StudentId()
{
    value = nextStudentId++;
    cout << "Take next student id " << value << endl;
}

// int constructor allows user to assign id
StudentId(int id)
{
    value = id;
    cout << "Assign student id " << value << endl;
}
protected:
int value;
};

class Student
{
public:
Student(const char* pName)
{
     cout << "constructing Student " << pName << endl;
     name = pName;
     semesterHours = 0;
     gpa = 0.0;
 }

protected:
string    name;
int       semesterHours;
float     gpa;
StudentId id;
};

int main(int argcs, char* pArgs[])
{
// create a couple of students
Student s1("Chester");
Student s2("Trude");

// wait until user is ready before terminating program
// to allow the user to see the program results
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

this is the output

> Take next student id 1000
>
> constructing Student Chester
>
> Take next student id 1001
>
> constructing Student Trude
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I am having a really hard time of understanding why the first student id is 1000 if value adds one to it and then prints it out

does this make sense

right in the constructor for studentId the two lines of code take `nextStudentId` and add one to it then it gets printed out

wouldn't the output be something like this:

> Take next student id 1001
>
> constructing Student Chester
>
> Take next student id 1002
>
> constructing Student Trude
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

hope you get what I am trying to say

### thanks

Luke

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ++ is the *post*-increment operator: it *first* reads the value (and assigns it to a variable), and only *then* increments it.

Contrast this with the *pre*-increment operator:

```
value = ++nextStudentId;
```

This would have the behavior you expect.

Take a look at this question for more information: [Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

Answer (score 5):

```
value = nextStudentId++;
```

This uses what is called the post-increment operator. Doing `nextStudentId++` will first use the current value of `nextStudentId` for `value` and *afterwards* increment it. So the first time round, `value` will be 1000 and `nextStudentId` will immediately afterwards become 1001, and so on.

If you instead do:

```
value = ++nextStudentId;
```

which is the pre-increment operator, you will see what you were expecting earlier.

Answer (score 4):

In C and C++ increment (and decrement) operators occurs in two forms

1. prefix - ++Object
2. sufix - Object++

The prefix form increments and then return value, however suffix form takes snapshot of value, increment the object and then returns snapshot previously taken.

```
T& T::operator ++(); // This is for prefix
T& T::operator ++(int); // This is for suffix
```

Please note second operator has a dummy int parameter, this is to ensure different signatures for these operators.

You can override these operator, but its make sure to maintain the semantics in overridden implementation to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
value = ++nextStudentId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how operators "x++" and "++x" works?

"x++" firstly returns value of x, and then it increments the x

for example:

```
int x = 1;
std::cout << x++ << std::endl; // "1" printed, now x is 2
std::cout << x << std::endl; // "2" printed
```

"++x" firstly increments the x, and then it returns incremented value

```
int y = 1;
std::cout << ++y << std::endl; // "2" printed, y is 2
std::cout << y << std::endl; // "2"
```