# how does if (i++) condition work?

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Increment and Pre Increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

I cant understand how the "if condition" works with the increment/decrement operator in this scenario:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main() 
{ 
  int n=0; 
  if(n++) 
  { 
    printf("C-DAC"); 
  } 
  else if(n--) 
  { 
    printf("ACTS"); 
  } 
}
```

Its output is ACTS.

what is happening in the IF condition?

Comment: please indent your code - all in column 1 makes it very hard to read - thanks.

Comment: Why are we answering this question AGAIN? :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`if (n++)` It checks if `n` is not equal to zero and then increments `n`

`else if (n--)` It checks if `n` is not equal to zero and then decrements `n`

Your first `if` statement is not true (because `n` is zero), then `n` is incremented, and `else if` statement is checked (`n` is equal to 1 at this point), `if (1)` is true and `printf("ACTS")` is called

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not specified anywhere in the program that it has to check whether n!=0... how does it understand this ??

Comment: Statement `if (n)` in `c++` is equal to `if (n != 0)` statement

Comment: There is actually no if condition at all, at least not ouside a debug build. As the program is written, the compiler can trivially prove at compile time that the first test is always false and the second test is always true, and the variable is not otherwise used. Thus it will reduce the program to `int main() { printf(ACTS"); return 0;}`

Comment: @Damon true, but we're talking about c++ itself, but not about compiler optimizations

Comment: @Anvay If Ribtok's answer solved your problem you should [**accept it**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the checkmark next to this answer. This will give you both some rep points and also mark this problem as solved

Comment: Thanx @Levon .. I didn't know this..!!! Accepted his answer now..!

Answer (score 3):

Both `n++` and `n--` are **post**-*increment/decrement* operations.

That means the value of the variable is used for evaluation in the current expression first *and only then changed*, (i.e., incremented/decremented *afterward*).

`0` means FALSE in a Boolean expression. Since `n` is initially `0`, the test in your first `if` fails and the `else` clause is evaluated.

At that point `n` has become `1` due to the `n++` in the first test, so this results in this test becoming true and

```
printf("ACTS");
```

to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

if(0++) ==> if(0)
else if(1--) ==> else if(1)

so ACTS is printed

Answer (score 2):

```
int n=0; 
if(n++)
```

Meaning: check and then increment by 1.

```
int n=0; 
if(++n)
```

Meaning: increment by 1 and then check.

Answer (score 2):

An int always gives true, unless it is zero.
The postincrement operator, `i++`, increments the `i` variable after the check.
If you had used the preincrement operator, `++i`, the incrementation would take place before the check.

Answer (score 2):

while checking your `IF` part, value of **n** is '**0**'. And because of the `i++` ,
'**n**' increments by **1**. So, now the value of **n** is **1**. So, while entering `ELSE` part, as value of **n** is **1** , it executes `ELSE` part.
And you are getting the output of the `ELSE` part.

Answer (score 1):

It first checks the condition that `n != 0` and *after* that it will increment the value of n

Answer (score 1):

The `++` and `--` operator not only modify the value, they also have a return value. Behaviour is different depending on the position: `++var` increases and returns the increased value, whereas `var++` increases but returns the old value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `++` and `--` do not 'have a return value'.  They are modifiers, not functions.

Answer (score 1):

because i is 0. `++i` would increment before evaluation, `i++` increments after

Answer (score 0):

The compiler reads the command in the **left to right** fashion. Meaning first it checks if the condition is true of false

```
if (n)
```

and then increments/decrements

```
 n = n +/- 1
```