# How a=3 and b=4?

Tags: java, switch-statement, post-increment, pre-increment

I found an interesting Programing question :

What will be the values of a,b,c,f after executing  this programe ?

```
int i=0,a=0,b=0,c=0,f=0;
while(i<=5){
switch(i++){
    case 1:++a;
    case 2:++b;
    break;
    case 3:
    case 4:++c;a++;b++;
    break;
    default:++f;
}
}
```

I thought that the values

a=2 , b=2 , c=2 and f=2   but

when i executed this programe i got a = 3, b = 4, c = 2 and f = 2.

I understood how c and f got it values 2 but how come a=3 and b=4.

(As per the syntax ++a and a++ are different as ++a  updates the value and then uses it
where as a++ uses the value and then updates it )

Can anyone explain how a and b got its values as 3 and 4.

UPDATE:

> Hey my doubt is : In i++ the intial value is 0 and not 1. But then how
> case 4 => a=3
>
> It should be a=2  and should incriment the value if
> there was any updation of 'a' in case 5 (which is not true)as i haven't given any
> substitution like a=a++.

Any Help appreciated.

Comment: I would step through your code in a debugger to see what each line does. It shows you the value of each variable at each line.

Comment: Looks like the old 'break fallthrough' homework to me

Comment: I hope its not his homework or atleast its just extra credit @edze . There are more valuable things to teach like CS Theory then how screwed up the switch statement is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey has the right idea. There is an easy-to-use debugger in Eclipse and all other mainstream IDEs. Stepping through code is always instructive.

Comment: a gets incremented when i is 1,3 and 4; b gets incremented when i is 1,2,3,4; ...

Comment: Checkout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html for more details

Comment: so that means the difference between i++ and ++i is not an issue in this case.

Comment: Hey my doubt is in i++ the intial value is 0 and not 1 but then how code case 4 => a=3 (it should be a=2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to do this exercise with paper and pen. Anyway:

1. i = 0 **==>** f =1;
2. i = 1 **==>** a = 1; b = 1; **(ther isn't break after case 1!)**
3. i = 2 **==>** b = 2;
4. i = 3 **==>** c = 1; a = 2; b = 3;
5. i = 4 **==>** c = 2; a = 3; b = 4;
6. i = 5 **==>** f = 2;

Comment: so that means the difference between i++ and ++i is not an issue in this case.wright!

Comment: @R41nB0wM47r1z right not in this case, but it would have been if you where assigning value like so a = ++x or a = x++ ;

Comment: If the switch contained ++i then the first iteration would begin from 1 and not from 0. This mean that finally the value of f would been 1 and not 2.

Comment: Hey my doubt is : In i++ the intial value is 0 and not 1. But then how  case 4 => a=3 (it should be a=2  and should incriment the value if there was any updation of 'a' in case 5 as i haven't give any substitution like a=a++)

Comment: Hum no one answered this doubt !In your ans case 5=>a=3(it should be a=2 and should incriment the value if there was any updation of 'a' in case 5 as i haven't give any substitution like a=a++)

Comment: What do you mean with 'sobstitution'? If you write a++; is the same as you write a = a + 1;

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you...

```
When i is 0 
    None of the case matched and went to default
    so a=0,b=0,c=0,f=1;

When i is 1 
    Case 1 and 2 will execute as there is no break after 1;
    so a=1,b=1,c=0,f=1;

When i is 2 
    Case 2 will execute
    so a=1,b=2,c=0,f=1; 

When i is 3 
    Case 3 and 4 will execute as there is no break after 3;
    so a=2,b=3,c=1,f=1; 

When i is 4 
    Case 4 will execute
    so a=3,b=4,c=2,f=1; 

When i is 5 
    Default will execute
    so a=3,b=4,c=2,f=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that switch statements support "fall through" - for i=2, only b is incremented, but for i=1 both are incremented.

Answer (score 0):

the pre and post increment ( ++a, and a++ ) are best explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4445841/623546) previous answer

**Update**
As pointed out in the comments bellow there is a fundamental difference in the C++ and Java implementation of those concepts. But here is a simple example in java

```
        x = 1;
        y = ++x;  Here y = 2 and x =2 because we first increment x and assign it to y

        x = 1;
        y = x++;  But here y = 1 and x = 2 because we first assign x to y and then increment x

in essense , y = x++ is equivalent to those 2 statements
            y =x;
            x = x + 1;
```

Comment: That's C++. These operators have a more well defined evaluation in Java.

Comment: @fgb is there any fundamental difference in both language implementation of the concept ?

Comment: @MimiEAM Yes, for example, from your link *"The compiler is free to [...] delay the increment until the end of the expression"* - That is not the case in Java. Also there is not a concept of lvalue in Java.