# ++ operator overload c++ Meaning

Tags: c++, overloading

I am new in C++ and I've got some questions. I saw `operator ++` overloading at complex numbers and I cant understand:

1. Why I create a `tmp` variable
2. why my first operator is `Complex &` and second it's just `Complex`
3. Why return *this;(i know cause of `Complex&` but why)
4. if i used Complex without & what would happened?(i run it and its the same result)

Don't look at comments it's Greek :)

```
Complex &   Complex::operator ++(){
     r=r+1;
     return *this;//to this einai to pointer tou trexontos alla 8eloume dereference ara vazoume *this gia na epistrepsoume refernce//
}

Complex     Complex::operator ++(int ){
     Complex tmp(*this);
     operator ++();
        return tmp;//ftiaxnoume ena tmp tou antikimenou pou exoume meta efarmozoume to operator++ kai epistrefoume to tmp//
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4445969/78845 for an explanation of pre- vs post-increment operators in C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the different signature (Complex& vs Complex) is because these operations i++ and ++i do different things. One returns a copy of the old value (the second one) by value, the first one returns a reference to the actual value if x - by reference

The tmp variable is needed because you need to return the old value after incrementing the value (thats what x++ does)

you need to return a reference to the current object - so return *this - this is a pointer to the current object; *this is the object

Comment: if i used complex without & what would be happened?

Answer (score 1):

2 - `Complex &` returns a reference to the same object, `Complex` returns a copy of it.

1 - that is why a temp variable is created, in order to increment the actual object but return the copy, in order to simulate the "use and then increment" postfix operator.

3 - because while `i++` returns a copy of `i` (and increments `i`), `++i` returns `i` incremented.

4 - the operator will return a copy of the incremented object, not the actual incremented object.

Comment: if i used complex without & what would be happened?

Comment: @user3135218 - in this particular case nothing bad. The `++` operator will return a copy of the incremented object instead of the incremented object. But when you do operator overloading, you really should follow the proper convention for return types and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With a variable x, you can write `++x` or `x++`.  Former will do a `++`, and if it is part of a bigger expression, use the new x. Latter will do the `++` too, but uses the old x for the current expression (it´s like the `++` comes a line after the current one).

If you overload `++`, you need to separate if it is prefixed or suffixed.
It looks somewhat strange, but if you mean the suffixed version, you need to have a nameless `int` as parameter of the function (nothing for prefix). There is no meaningful value passed or something,
it´s just to make a difference between the two possibilites.

So, in the suffix variant, you´ll have a temporary copy to keep
the old value while you´re doing the `++` (ant return the old value for this one time).