# C++ Pre and Post increment compiler behaviour

Tags: c++

I was writing very simple c++ code using pre and post increment operators, and I came across this mysterious behavior of c++ compiler. Can anyone please explain what actually happens while executing each of the print statement below....

Code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=5;
   cout <<i++<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output of the code given above is:

```
5
```

Now I understand that since this is post increment the value of the i will be increased by 1 after the print statement!

Now lets print something different!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=5;
   cout <<i++<<i--<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is...

```
45
```

Now I don't understand why the value of the i was decremented here even though I didn't decrement it and also I used post increment operation!

Now also if I write the same code as this...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=5;
   cout <<i++<<i<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is

```
56
```

This output is expected and I can understand what really goes on here!

To make thing even more interesting, I eventually tried all the pre and post increment operations in single print statement, and I was just amazed by the output that I obtained!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=5;
   cout <<i++<<i--<<++i<<--i<<i<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

output that I obtained was

```
45555
```

So please explain me what really happens when I print a single statement using pre and post increment operations!

And I don't understand the behavior of compiler in 2nd code segment above! Why the value of i was decremented to 4!

Comment: You are "playing" with undefined behaviour, and thus the result is up to whatever the compiler decides to do - the spec does not define which order these things should happen in. Only what the final value for ONE of the `i++` or `i--` will produce - more than one in the same "sequence point" (simply put one line of code [or more, up to a semicolon], but there are a few sequence points that aren't semicolon)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept?rq=1
(Or one of the other 10 or so "related" links on the right of this question)