# Iterator begin() should contain 3, output says 2?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Why does the iterator pointing to the beginning of a list output the second value? Why does a.begin()++ leave begin() ahead and is there a better implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
//3,2,1
int main() {
    list<int> a;
    a.insert(a.begin(),1);              
    cout << *(a.begin()) << endl;
    a.insert(a.begin(),3);
    cout << *a.begin()<< endl;
    a.insert(a.begin()++,2);
    list<int>::iterator iterator = a.begin();
    iterator++;
    cout << *iterator << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
1
3
3
```

Expected output:

```
1
3
2
```

Edit:
"Because you put 2 at the start of the list. Remember that a.begin()++ is doing post-incrementing ie, it increments after all other operations. Try your code with ++a.begin() and see if it does what you expect"- @Ben

Typographic error, thanks Ben.

Comment: I get your expected output using both gcc and VS compilers.

Comment: That's the behaviour I'd expect if you used `++it` instead of `it++`, i.e. prefix increment operator. Maybe there's a bug in the implementation of the postfix operator? What is `distance(a.begin(), a.begin()++)`?

Comment: @ateneaMinerva  If it is indeed so then it can be a bug of the library.

Comment: Just wondering, you are not using the STL, but the C++ standardlibrary supplied with your compiler, right? Which one and which version, btw?

Comment: Wait: Your topic says "output contains 2" and that's what you claim as expected output!? Which one is right?

Comment: This is overall very confusing .. your code does exactly what it is supposed to. I suspect that you think that `a.begin()++` changes where the start of the list is. It does not ....

Comment: [In your last edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34073453/3), it is clear your output is as it should be, since you have advanced `iterator` past the element containing `2`. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I use clang-700.1.76 but the main problem is the code was wrong, now I have edited it. The question is why a.begin()++ doesn't show 2.

Comment: @ateneaMinerva Because you put 2 at the start of the list. Remember that `a.begin()++` is doing post-incrementing ie, it increments after all other operations. Try your code with `++a.begin()` and see if it does what you expect.

Comment: @Ben, Ah, if that was the intent, the question was very unclear.

Comment: @Ben HOLY S**T I didn't remember the difference between post-increment and pre-increment, this is the answer I needed, thank you all.

Comment: Ok then this should absolutely be closed as simple typographic error. Also @jxh ... looks like i am a mind reader:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was simply forgetting that `a.insert(a.begin()++,2);` is equivalent to the `a.insert(a.begin(), 2)` in this case. This is because a [*post-increment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept) will add `2` to the beginning of the list then increment the iterator. If you want your expected output then you will need to use the pre-increment operator. ie:

```
a.insert(++a.begin(), 2)
```

Comment: Nice catch Ben, I didn't think that he would miss that, +1!

Answer (score 5):

The code is fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
//3,2,1
int main() {
    list<int> a;
    a.insert(a.begin(),1);
    cout << *(a.begin()) << endl;
    a.insert(a.begin(),3);
    cout << *a.begin()<< endl;
    a.insert(a.begin()++,2);
    list<int>::iterator iterator = a.begin();
    cout << *iterator << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
2
```

Check at [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kMVvEH) too.