# Arrays a[count++]

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a beginner in C++ so please bear with me. Below is just a part of the full program.

When the user inputs the first number  (assume '3'), it goes to the if statement.
a[count ++] then becomes a[1] (if I'm not wrong, because count is initially 0). The array element a[1] thus stores the input which is 3. If so, then didn't the program just skip a[0]?

```
int readarray(int a[], int capacity) {
int count = 0; 
    int input; 
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number (-1 to stop):  "; 
        cin >> input; 
        if (input != -1) {
            a[count++] = input; 
        }
    } while (input != -1 && count << capacity); 
    return count;
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::array`?

Comment: Why don't you use your debugger?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept

Comment: I think the downvotes are somewhat harsh. This is a question about the semantics of post increment,  which are not particularly obvious (and frequently misunderstood).

Comment: @EdHeal Let beginner look around a bit first. Moreover, using std::array doesn't really solve the problem asked. It's more about how incrementing works.

Comment: That is why I put it as a comment @Saraph

Comment: @AlanStokes But it is very easy to look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `count++` is a post increment operator. It uses the current value of `count` in the expression and also increments `count`. It's not defined how or when the increment happens so any other uses of `count` in the same statement could have unexpected results.

The statement is equivalent to writing

```
a[count] = input;
count = count + 1;
```

As a matter of personal opinion I think you should never use the pre/post increment/decrement operators in an expression. It doesn't produce any more efficient code, it is rather less readable and tends to end up with off by one errors.

Comment: "*It returns the value of count then increments it*" is not entirely correct. It could also increment first, then return count-1 (the old value of count). Or it could interleave the two actions. The point is, no such temporal ordering is implied.

Comment: @AlanStokes - arggh, sorry, it's too early in the morning

Comment: @melpomene - true. clarified

Comment: Now it's less wrong but also less clear, I think. "*... and also increments it*" can be read as referring to "value". And your "equivalent" rewrite still shows an ordering.

Comment: @melpomene re-re-correct while you were commenting.

Comment: You don't really "return" anything, because we're talking about an expression, not a jump statement. Evaluated expressions have values, and expression evaluation can have side effects. The value of the expression `x++` is the original value of `x` (and it is an rvalue), and the side effect is that `x` is incremented.

Answer (score 4):

No, postfix increment (`x++`) returns the *old* value of the variable. So `a[count++]` increments `count` from 0 to 1, but uses 0 (the old value of `count`) as the index.

By the way, `count << capacity` looks wrong. Did you mean `count < capacity`?

Comment: For completeness: have a look at ++x. This one would do what you expect.

Comment: An addition to the comments on count++… ++count would work in your example as it's evaluated before use not after.

Comment: @Burrito *++count would work* is exactly wrong: It would make the code not work.

Comment: My understanding of ++count is first loop it assigns to index 1 then 2 etc?

Comment: @Burrito Yes, thus leaving index 0 uninitialized (and potentially writing out of bounds).

Comment: I think I have misread the question, my bad :) thought that was the behaviour op was after

Answer (score -2):

Instead of a[count++] you can do if(input != -1){a[count] = input;  count++}. In this way the value will be assigned to current array index say at start, it will be assigned to a[0] and then count will be incremented to 1. So next iteration will have a[1].