# C++ and ++ operators

Tags: c++, operators, cout

so I am looking at the following snippet of code

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
b = a++;
cout << ++b;
```

My understanding line by line is:

1. initiate a = 3
2. initiate b = 2;
3. assign the value of (a+1) to b, so b = 4;
4. print b+1, which is 5.

However this is wrong, can someone explain this in simple terms? I am new to C++

Comment: You are confusing pre-increment and post-increment. `a++` and `++a` are not the same. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ when an increment or decrement is used in an expression, the position of "++" or "--" matters.
If the operator is before a variable then the increment or decrement will be done before the end of the expression, in the opposite situation the increment or decrement will be done after the entire  expression is executed.

```
int b = ++a; // first add +1 to a, then assign a to b
int b = a++; // assign a to b, then add +1 to a
```

Answer (score 4):

In the statement:

```
b = a++
```

`a` is evaluated for the assignment to `b` and **after** that `a` is then incremented so `a = a+1`.

On the other hand:

```
b = ++a
```

Increments `a` so `a = a+1` **before** `a` is then evaluated for assignment to `b`.

You can look deeply here:

[Pre-increment or post-increment in C/C++](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4410601/Pre-increment-or-post-increment-in-C-C-)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

- initiate a = 3
- initiate b = 2;
- assign the value of (a) to b, so b = 3 and increment a to 4;
- print b+1, which is 4.

Comment: It'd be good to explain prefix vs postfix