# Am I using index argument of callback function in .map ( ) wrongly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capitalise the first letter of each word in a sentence. However, the output I got from my code below is: "I'm a little teapot". I tried finding detailed explanations of how the index argument for the callback function for the map function works but found none. I want to instruct it to capitalise the letter if the element before it is a space. What's wrong with my code?

```
function titleCase(str) {
str= str.toLowerCase().split("");

var newArr= str.map( function(i,j){

if ( j===0 ){
return i.toUpperCase();}
else if (str[j--]===" "){
return i.toUpperCase();
}
 return i;

});

return newArr.join("");
}


console.log(titleCase("i'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: Hey, Emily, was my explanation clear?

Comment: See this for more information regarding [how post increments and decrements work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept).

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Instead of looping by character, split using spaces, and then loop over the words, capitalizing the first character of each one.

Comment: @torazaburo This looks like a homework gone wrong, and the OP wanted to understand what's wrong and how increments and decrements work. Reopening the question as it is not dupe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's crazy here.

```
else if (str[j--]===" ") {
```

You are modifying the `j` value. You shouldn't do that. You should do:

```
else if (str[j-1]===" ") {
```

Also, it is a post decrement operator. This is highly dangerous, as it leads to infinite looping. Plus, this always gives the current value, which applies the upper case on the space.

Making that small change fixed it:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  var newArr = str.map(function(i, j) {
    if (j === 0) {
      return i.toUpperCase();
    } else if (str[j-1] === " ") {
      return i.toUpperCase();
    }
    return i;
  });
  return newArr.join("");
}

console.log(titleCase("i'm a little tea pot"));
```

**Output:**

```
I'm A Little Tea Pot
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm completely new to coding so there's a lot I still don't know. One question: how is "j-1" different from "j--"? I thought it's the same.

Comment: @Emily Yes, it is confusing. `j--` will loosely equate to `(j = j - 1; return j + 1;)` Now do you understand the problem?

Comment: Why does it "return j+1"?

Comment: @Emily Because it is **post decrement**. It returns the value first, then it decrements.

Comment: @Emily See this for more information regarding [how post increments and decrements work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept).

Comment: @Emily Any other questions?

Comment: Just to check, should it be "return j" instead? It returns j first then decrements it by 1.

Comment: @Emily I was trying to make you understand. It returns the j value first, and then decrements it. Yes!