# Why is n += 1 not equivalent to n++

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain to me why the 2 blocks of code below result in different values?

**Double plus**

```
let n = 2;
let x = n++;

// n = 3, x = 2
```

**Plus equals**

```
let n = 2;
let x = n += 1;

// n = 3, x = 3
```

Comment: `let x = ++n;` should yield the same value. It depends on where you put the ++ for when the increment happens.

Comment: ++ will assign the value first then increment n by 1 because it is post increment operator

Comment: check this link for more understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept

Comment: `x = n++;` is equivalent to `x=n; n = n+1;`