# C: order of evaluation in a conditional expression

Tags: c

There is the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int* a_p = a;
    float x = 1.5;

    while(x > (*a_p++))
    {
        printf("*a_p = %d\n", *a_p);
    }

    printf("*a_p = %d", *a_p);
    return 0;
}
```

The question would be which is the result of the final `printf` statement?
I would judge that the order is:

1) inside `while`, `a_p` address is incremented => `*a_p` is 1 (`a[1]`)

2) 1.5 is compared with 1

3) inside `while`, `a_p` address is incremented again => `*a_p` is 2 (`a[2]`)

4) 1.5 is compared with 2

5) 2 is printed for `*a_p`

I have tried with 3 compilers and the result is 3.
Why 3 is the correct result? Is first done the comparison and then the pointer is incremented meaning that at step 4 from above, after the comparison is done, `*a_p` is 3?
Is this always the behavior (is this behavior defined) or is compiler dependent?

Comment: `a_p` is incremented *after* the comparison, regardless of the result of the comparison.

Comment: Tried doing some research? See the second answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept for example.

Comment: I have researched it quite a lot, but I was focused of "order of evaluation". I have completely missed the *pre* and *post* increment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's how post increment works. The while condition is true for `0`th and `1`th index but when it evaluates to false - the pointer value is already increased as a result it points to index `4` having value `3`.

`*p++` the value of it will be `*p` where this `p` is the old one which is not incremented. Same happens with `a_p` is here - last time when it is compared the value `*a_p++` is `2` but the new value of `a_p` is pointing to the `4th` index. Loop ends and `3` is printed.