# awk numbered columns and ignore errors

Tags: bash, awk, numbers, range

The following works well and captures all 2nd column values for S_nn. The goal is to add numbers in the 2nd column.

```
awk -F "," '/s_/ {cons = cons + $2} END {print cons}' G.csv
```

How can I change this to add only when nnn is between N1 and N2 e.g. s_23 and s_24?

Also is it possible to consider 1 if a line has junk instead of numbers in the 2nd column?

```
S_22, 1
S_23, 0
S_24, 1
S_25, 1
S_26, ?
```

Sample input: sum s_24 to s_26

Sample output: 1+1+1=3 (the last one is for error)

Comment: Please show us sample Input in CODE TAGS and expected output in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Also please do add what are the conditions or adding 0 or 1 to 5th column? What do you mean by junk characters? and what is `nnn` between N1 and N2 too here?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is rather simple, all you need to do is perform a simple numeric test.

```
awk -v start=24 -v stop=26 '
     BEGIN { FS="[_,]" }
     (start <= $2 ) && ($2 <= stop) { s = s + (($3==$3+0)?$3:1) }
     END{ print s+0 }' <file>
```

which outputs

```
3
```

How does it work:

- line 1 : defines the start and stop fields
- BEGIN statement redefines the field separator as a `_` or a `,`, so now we have 3 fields.
- the second line checks if field 2 (the number) is between `start` and `stop`, if so perform the sum.
- the field 3 is checked if it is a number by testing the condition `$3==$3+0`, if this fails, it is assumed to be `1`

If you want to see the numbers printed, you can do :

```
awk -v start=24 -v stop=26 '
     BEGIN{ FS="[_,]" }
     (start <= $2 ) && ($2 <= stop) {
        v = ($3==$3+0)?$3:1
        s = s + v
        printf "%s%d", (c++?"+":""), v
     }
     END{ printf "=%d\n", s }' <file>
```

output :

```
1+1+1=3
```

The `printf` statement always prints `"+"$3` except on the first time. This is checked by keeping track of a counter `c`. By default the value of `c` is set to zero. The entry `(c++?"+":"")` determines if we are printing the first entry or not. `c++` will return the value of `c` and afterwards sets `c` to the value `c+1`, This is called a [post increment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept). Thus, the first time, `c=0` and `(c++?"+":"")` returns `""` and sets `c` to `1`. The second time, `(c++?"+":"")` returns `"+"` and sets `c` to `2`.

Comment: the second block worked well, the first one needs some correction: returned a 1

Comment: how is c++ checking for end of inputs?

Comment: @Tims, I've updated the first block (missed some brackets).

Comment: oops...I was asking about (c++?"+":"") in your line of awk code