# Control statements and loops

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 5, no = 10;
    do {
        no /= c;
    } while(c--);

    printf ("%d\n", no);

    return 0;

}
```

Please help me trace the while loop. 
I think it stops at one stage,  but that is not the case, It executes even when c=0,hence gives runtime error.
Please explain

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `c--` and `--c` is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Comment: When C is 1, the loop will continue after decrementing 1, and integer division by 0 has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 8th line `while(c--)` to 
`while(--c)` 
c-- will check the condition and then it will decrease the value of C variable