# What does this statement means basically in count[str[j]]++?

Tags: c++, word-count

My question is regarding a statement which I am having trouble understanding.

The statement is :

```
count[str[j]]++
```

where:

- count is a count array I took to count each char in a string,
- str is my given string, and
- j is loop.

If someone can explain the whole statement that will be good.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down. `count` is getting an element from array count. The index of that element is `str[j]`. Since j is in a loop, it will change. Finally, `++` is simply incrementing that value of the element in array  `count`. Hope this helps!

Comment: So lets say my str[0] is 'A' so count [A] but count is int array so I am lost a little bit at this point how can count[A] happen ?

Comment: Look, all you gave was that one statement. If you like, you can put the snippet of code in.

Comment: @WaqasMoosa characters are integers in C and C++

Answer (score 0):

Given the `count` variable, locate the value of the index `str[j]` where `j` is the index provided by your iteration.  `str[j]` will return the character of the variable str at index j.  So, for instance, if `str` is "Example", then `str[1]` is "x".  Finally, the statement takes the index of count `count["x"]` and post-increments it, so that `count["x"]` is increased by 1

To learn a bit more about post and pre increment, take a look at this answer

[Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Comment: Oh thank you. Actually I know post increment and Pre-increment where I was stuck was my str[1] is 'x' so if count is my int array how it's index is a char that's where I was getting confused.
Because the program is finding the duplicate letter in string using int *count

Comment: `str[1]` is 'x' (a single character, not a string of one character).  Then you should use `count['x']` since `str[j]` is a character and not a string.