# In an increment, why does the value of the variable get passed instead of the value as well as the increment?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

Here's my code:

```
var x = 3;
var y = x++;
y += 1;
```

Output: `y = 4`

I know the computer is right, but I'm not sure why the computer is right. 
**y** gets assigned the value **3** from **x**, then it increments it to **4** in line 2. So, the output from line 3 should be **5**, correct?

From what I've read, **y** gets assigned the value of **x** before the increment happens, but when it does happen, why does the value of **y** not change?

Comment: Assignment of a value from one variable to another in JavaScript involves a *copy* of the value. In `y = x++;` no permanent relationship between `x` and `y` is established; it's a one-time copy.

Comment: *"y gets assigned the value of x"* That's the crucial point. `x++` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`. So `y = x++` is the same as `y = x; x = x + 1;`. `x` is assigned a new value, but that has no effect on the value of `y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your assignment `y = x++;` the value of **y** is first assigned to **x** and then the variable **x** gets incremented by 1. By performing this operation **y** becomes 3 and x is 4. Then after running y +=1 computer will calculate 3+1 = 4

If you're expecting **y** to be 5 you should do `y = ++x;`. By doing this **x** will first get incremented by 1 and then assigned to **y** so we will have y = 4 and x = 4 following the y += 1 (4+1=5)

Comment: Oh okay, I see. **y** gets assigned **x**, and then **x** gets incremented by **1** because that's the variable being targetted by the program in this instance. 

So **y** becomes **3**. Then the value of **x** gets incremented by **1** since they have no relation to each other.

Comment: Exactly, yes. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between **pre-increment** (`++x`) and **post-increment** (`x++`).

A pre-increment operator is used to increment the value of a variable before using it in a expression. In the **pre-increment**, value is first incremented and then used inside the expression. Let's say we have:

```
a = ++x;
```

Here, if the value of ‘x’ is 10 then value of ‘a’ will be 11 because the value of ‘x’ gets modified before using it in the expression. This is equivalent with:

```
x = x + 1;
a = x;
```

A **post-increment** operator is used to increment the value of variable after executing expression completely in which post increment is used. In the Post-Increment, value is first used in a expression and then incremented. Let's say we have:

```
a = x++;
```

Here, suppose the value of ‘x’ is 10 then value of variable ‘a’ will be 10 because old value of ‘x’ is used. This is equivalent with:

```
a = x;
x = x + 1;
```

You can read more on the interned about this (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)).

Cheers!

```js
// Post-increment example
console.log("post-increment examples");
let x = 10;
a = x++;
console.log(x, a);

x = 10;
a = x;
x = x + 1;
console.log(x, a);

// Pre-increment example
console.log("pre-increment examples");
x = 10;
a = ++x;
console.log(x, a);

x = 10;
x = x + 1;
a = x;
console.log(x, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

`x++` return the value and then add 1. See this:

```js
var x = 3;
var y = x++;// x return 3 and then add 1, y is 3 
y += 1;//3 + 1 = 4
console.log(y)
console.log(x)//x return 4
```