# Double pointer **src and operation (*(*src)++ = reg_offset)

Tags: c++, c

I'm newer in C/C++, I really confuse about a function that executes complex operation. I just want to know how it works ? What does function mean ?

```
void writetoXX(unsigned int **src, unsigned int reg_offset, unsigned int reg_data){
    *(*src)++ = reg_offset;
    *(*src)++ = reg_data;
}
```

Any idea ??

Update my understanding:

```
void writetoXX(unsigned int **src, unsigned int reg_offset, unsigned int reg_data) {
    *(*src)++ = reg_offset;
    *(*src)++ = reg_data;
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = { 0 };

    int *p = a;
    printf("Before !!\n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
    writetoXX(&p, 20, 30);
    printf("After !!! \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

After run this program, I see that the function writetoXX change value arr[0][0] and arr[0][1] to 20 and 30. It means that the function is used for write data to 2 consecutive blocks.

And output is below:

```
Before !!
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
After !!
20 30 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: There must be a clearer way to write this code that is just as performant.

Comment: in c++ (as the question is tagged c++) there is: just declare `*c`  as a parameter by reference, as in `writetoXX(unsigned int *&pointer,...)` and then write `*(pointer)++  = reg_offset;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src` is a pointer to a pointer to an `unsigned int`, for example this is used for bidimensional arrays. Because of the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the routine does:

- take `*src`, it is a pointer to an `unsigned int`
- `(*src)++` increments the pointer, such that it points to the next `unsigned int`. It is a [post increment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4445706/8769985), so it returns the value before the increment.
- `*(*src)++` is the `unsigned int` pointed by `*src` *before* the increment `++`

So in summary, you take `* src` which is a pointer to `unsigned int`, you assign the first pointed data to `reg_offset`, then you increment such pointer, then you assign the next element to `reg_data`, and finally you increment again the pointer `*src`.

Answer (score 2):

Double pointer is a variable which stores address of another pointer variable.

Consider this `*(*src)++ = reg_offset;`

In one line: The value of `reg_offset` is stored at current address stored in `src` and the address in `src` is incremented.

You can consider this happening in the following order.
1) As you know `src` is a variable which is storing address of another pointer or memory space.

2) So `(*src)` whill give address of the pointed variable or memory space.

3) Due to operator precedence, `(*src)++` takes place. Which you can read like, after executing the current line, increment the **address value stored in `src`**.

4) Now `*(*src)` Which is the memory space with address stored in `(*src)`. So `*(*src) = reg_offset;` will copy the value of `reg_offset` to that address. I have removed `++` in this line just for clarity.

5) When the second line `*(*src)++ = reg_data;` is about to be executed, the `(*src)` will be pointing to next address. So `reg_data` is written to next address.

Please note, `next address` does not mean `current_address+1`. It actually means `current_address+sizeof(data type)`. If`unsigned int` is 4 byte in your compiler, then `next_address = current_address+4`

You can print content of `(*src)` in between the lines and verify.