# how value of a pointer is same even after incrementing the address, for variable its different

Tags: c, pointers

In the below program I am getting same value for different pointer operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        *(ptr + i) = i;

    printf("%d ", *ptr++);
    printf("%d ", (*ptr)++); 
    printf("%d ", *ptr); ---------> o/p: 2
    printf("%d ", *++ptr);--------> o/p: 2
    printf("%d ", ++*ptr);
}
```

Output: `0 1 2 2 3`

My doubt is how `*ptr` and `*++ptr` is printing same value. It should be different as we  incrementing the pointer address

The post- and pre-increment for a variable I can understand, here both are pre-increment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Comment: After incrementing the value at orig_ptr[1], it has the same value as orig_ptr[2].  This should not be a suprise.  1 + 1 = 2

Comment: Your program does not only increment the pointer. It also changes the array.

Comment: Your program is in C, remove `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 5):

With `(*ptr)++)`, you increment the value to which `ptr` points, such that your "array" contains two equal values then, i.e. `ptr[0]==2` and `ptr[1]==2`. That's why `*ptr` and `*++ptr` yield the same value, though they point to different addresses.

Remove the `printf("%d ", (*ptr)++)` and you'll see clearer.