# Post increment behavior when throwing an exception

Tags: java, undefined-behavior

Came accross this weird issue yesterday. Can't seem to find any logical explanation in the java spec for the following...

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;

        try {
            bork(i++);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    private static void bork(int i) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

One would think post-increment would not happen because bork throws the exception, but it does!

What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: `i++` is executed before the call to bork, I guess

Comment: `i++` increments `i` and evalutes to the previous value. That has to happen before the evaluated value can be passed to a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i++` operation is invoked, before the method `bork()` is invoked.
That's the reason why it's still incremented.

So:

1. `i++` is invoked.
2. As a result it *returns* the state of `i` before the increment.
3. At the same time the actual state of `i` is incremented. So the value of `i` is now `1`.
4. `bork(0)` is invoked.
5. The exception is thrown.
6. The exception is handled (by doing nothing)
7. The current state of `i` is printed which is equal to `1`.

Comment: That's exactly what I saw in the bytecode as well! I noticed aload, iinc and then the invoke. It's just really counter intuitive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept - Maybe this topic can give you more insight. Also if you consider my answer helpful, please mark it at as a correct one. :)