# When do we use i++ and when do we use ++i in C++

Tags: algorithm, c++11, for-loop

When I do exercises, I always use for loops: `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` But sometimes I got wrong with them, I have tried in many ways to fix, but it ran only when I turn the `i++` in for loop to `++i`. I wonder when can we use `i++` and when `++i`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i++` and `++i` are statements and expressions at the same time.

They both increment the `i` variable, obviously, and both return the value of `i` as their result, but `i++` returns the value of `i` *before* it's incremented whereas `++i` returns the value of `i` *after* it's incremented.

If you don't use it as an expression but just as a statement, either form works equally well. If you do use the result, it depends what you want to achieve, e.g. in `a[i++] = 1` you write to `a` and then increment the index.

Comment: Nitpick: *every* expression can be used as a statement, from the production "[*statement*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt): *attribute-specifier-seq* opt [*expression-statement*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement)"

Answer (score 1):

`++i` is called pre increment while `i++` is called postincrement.

`++i` increments the value of `i` and then returns `i`,
`i++` returns the value of `i` and then increments.

Both of them increase the variable `i` by one. It's like saying `i = i + 1`. The difference is subtle. If you're using it in a loop like this, there's no difference:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two typical implementations where `T` represents any type:

`++i` prefix increment

```
T& operator++() {   // returns by reference
    // increment *this by 1 here
    return *this;
}
```

`i++` postfix increment

```
T operator++(int) { // returns by value
    T copy(*this);  // make a copy of the current state
    ++(*this);      // increment *this by 1 here, using the pre-increment operator
    return copy;    // return the copy
}
```