# Trying to print out the value of *ptr++, to understand how it works

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand the usage of `*ptr++`. Below is the code I have used (Scenario 1)

```
#include<iostream> 

int main()

{
    int a[5];
    a[0] = 3;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 4;
    a[3] = 7;
    a[4] = 9;
    int* ptr;
    ptr = &a[0];

    std::cout << *ptr << " ";
    std::cout << *ptr++ ;

}
```

I have read that the precedence is '++' first, and then dereferencing. So I expected that the output would be `3 2`. However, the output I obtained is `3 3`.

Now, in Scenario 2, if I try

```
int* ptr;
ptr=&a[0];
*ptr++;
std::cout<< *ptr;
```

(with all lines of code before `int* ptr` remaining the same), I obtain the output as `2`.

So how is `*ptr++` working, and in Scenario 2, isn't `*ptr++` working the same as a simple `ptr++`?

Comment: You need to do ++ptr if you want to increment ptr before dereferencing. `std::cout << *ptr << " "; std::cout << *++ptr ;` prints `3 2` More on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept

Comment: Okay, yes, understood, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence means that `*ptr++` is interpreted as `*(ptr++)` instead of `(*ptr)++`.

What surprised you is the unusual meaning of `(ptr++)`. That meaning is "increment ptr, but first use the old value". So `*(ptr++)` dereferences the old value of `ptr`.

The **statement** `*ptr++;` ignores the value you got by dereferencing `ptr++`, but still does the increment.

Comment: @PranavKrishnan. `ptr` is indeed updated to `&a[1]`, but `*` still works on `&a[0]`, and that's what is printed. Also, you assume the order of precedence is also the order of execution, which is just not the case.

Answer (score 1):

`*ptr++` does the following steps:

1. Create a copy of `ptr` (part of post-increment operation)
2. Dereference copy returned by post-increment using `*`
3. Increment `ptr` (part of post-increment operation)

So when you write `std::cout << *ptr++;`, you print dereferenced copy of original `ptr` (from before incrementing).

When you separate it to two lines like this:

```
*ptr++;
std::cout<< *ptr;
```

It becomes equivalent to this:

```
ptr++;
std::cout<< *ptr;
```

-you discard the dereference result in `*ptr++;` and dereference the already incremented pointer later in `std::cout <<`

Answer (score 1):

You said that "I have read that the precedence is '++' first, and then dereferencing", and this is where you made mistake.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence, 
you can see `a++   a--  Suffix/postfix increment and decrement` 
has higher precedence(Precedence 2) 
while `*a   Indirection (dereference)` is only Precedence 3.

The smaller is the number, the higher is the precedence
This is why `*ptr++` should be interpreted as `*(ptr++)`