# Can't understand a JavaScript function return

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am new to JS and encountered several new thins. For example I saw this piece of code:

```
function baz() {
    var x = 1;
    return {
        foo: function foo() {return ++x},
        bar: function foo() {return --x},
    };
}

var closures = baz();
alert(closures.foo(),closures.bar());
```

It is supposed to show a shared variable. My question is - what is being returned?

Is it simply an object with two functions foo() and bar()?
Thanks

Yotam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's "simply an object with two functions foo() and bar()".

But this function is also declared in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), which means it can have this private property `x` which

- is visible and modifiable by both functions
- can't be read or modified otherwise

The main differences with

```
var x = 1;
var closures = {
    foo: function() {return ++x},
    bar: function() {return --x},
};
```

is that

- x is protected by the closure creating the object
- there can be no name conflict regarding x, and the global namespace isn't cluttered

Answer (score 3):

The function `baz` returns an object with two properties (`foo` and `bar`). The values of those two properties are functions (both of which modify and return the value of the same `x` variable).

Answer (score 1):

Yo can even omit the `foo()` after function, because those properties will be named as you see, and those functions can be anonymous as well so:
`return {
var foo: function() {return ++x},
var bar: function() {return --x},
};`

So you have object with properties which are functions.

Answer (score 0):

The function `baz` sets a variable `x` to be 1 and then creates returns an object. This object has two fields one being `foo` and the other being `bar`. A little quick thing about objects is that if you want to access a field you simply need to call `object.fieldname`. We'll get more into that later.

The functions `foo` and `bar` are pretty simply. If you aren't sure what ++x and --x does here is a good Stackoverflow question:

[Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

Basically it is saying it will perform the statement and then increment or decrement x. Because it is returning x I believe it will return 1, and then increment or decrement x.

At the end of the function a variable called `closures` is defined and this is the object that is returned from the function. Like I said before, in order to access the fields, all you would need to do is do `object.fieldname` which in this case would be `closures.foo()` or `closures.bar()` (the parentheses are necessary to run the function).

I just tested it out and your alert shows 2. I believe the reason is that it doesn't understand the syntax of `alert(int,int)` so it shows the first alert only.