# Why do people write --i?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, language-agnostic, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

I've seen things like `i++` commonly used in, say, `for` loops. But when people use `--` instead of `++`, for some reason some tend to write `--i` as opposed to `i--`.

Last time I checked, they both work (at least in JavaScript). Can someone tell me if this is so in other C-family languages, and if it is, why do some people prefer `--i` to `i--`?

Comment: This isn't language agnostic and have different answers for C and C++, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the preference for prefix (`++i`) vs. postfix (`i++`) varies depending on whether it's an increment or a decrement.

As for *why*, I prefer prefix where possible because my native language is English, which has mostly a verb-before-object structure ("eat dinner", "drive car"), so "increment `i`" or "decrement `i`" is more natural for me than "`i` decrement". Of course, I'll happily use postfix if I'm using the result and I need the value *prior* to the increment in an expression (rather than the incremented value).

Comment: uh prefix is "always" at least as efficient as postfix, and might be more efficients. As explained http://stackoverflow.com/a/1813008/511302 here

Answer (score 12):

`++i` is faster than `i++`. Why? See the simple explication.

### i++

`i++` will increment the value of i, but return the pre-incremented value.

- `temp = i`
- `i` is incremented
- `temp` is returned

Example:

```
i = 1;
j = i++;
(i is 2, j is 1)
```

### ++i

`++i` will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value.

Example:

```
i = 1;
j = ++i;
(i is 2, j is 2)
```

This is simillar for `--i` and `i--`.

Comment: But why would anyone do `i++` but `--i`? That's the question.

Comment: The compiler can easily detect if the temp is used or not. So I would doubt that the code is faster.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: Yeah. There's an entire [question devoted to that for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c). TL;DR - Any vaguely-recent compiler will optimize away the difference, probably even if you *do* use the resulting value. In Java, the bytecode is identical if you don't use the result. If you do, it's just a matter of the order of the opcodes (with local ints, I didn't go in depth), `iinc / iload_1` vs. `iload_1 / iinc`. Of couse, the JIT may get involved at some point. Still, since I prefer prefix... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Historically the increment/decrement operator were motivated by stack management. When you push an element on the stack:

```
*(stackptr++) = value
```

when you pop:

```
value = *(--stackptr)
```

(these were converted to single ASM instructions)

So one gets used to increment-after and decrement-before.

You can see another idiomatic example in filling in direct and reverse order:

```
for (p=begin;p!=end;) 
    *(p++) = 42;

for (p=end;p!=begin;) 
    *(--p) = 42;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty much a preference thing, that only comes into play if you're doing the pre- or post-increment on types that are more complicated than primitives.

Pre-increment ("`++i`") returns the value of `i` *after* it has been incremented, and post-increment ("`i++`") returns the value *before* increment.  So, if `i` was of a complicated type that had overloaded the pre-increment and post-increment operators, the pre-increment operator can just return the object, whereas the post-increment would have to return a copy of the object, which could well be less efficient if the object is substantial.  And in most cases (for loop increments, etc.), the value is ignored anyways.

Like I said, most of the time, not a problem, and just a preference thing.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++,`++` and `--` operators have both prefix form: `++i` and `--i`, and suffix form: `i++` and `i--`. Former means evaluate-then-use and latter means use-then-evaluate. The difference is only relevant when either form is used as part of an expression. Otherwise it's a matter of preference or style (or lack thereof).

F.ex., in `int i = 0; int n = ++i;`, `i` is first incremented and then its value, now 1, is assigned to `n`. In `n = i++` value of `i`, still 1, is assigned to `n` and is then incremented, with `i == 2` now.

When used as a statement, that is: `i++; ++i;` both forms are equivalent.

Comment: The last statement in your post is not entirely true. For basic types, the compiler may optimize by replacing `i++` with `++i` if the result isn't used. If it doesn't perform this optimization, you may get a (very small) difference in performance. However, for user-defined types with overloaded `operator++`, this optimization is not allowed (because the compiler can't guarantee that you've correctly implemented the two to have the expected relationship). This means that, for user-defined types in C++, which form you choose actually affects the result.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is pre-incrementing or post-incrementing (and likewise with decrementing).

Quoting the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) on the topic that shows up as the second Google result for "c decrement":

```
int  x;
int  y;

// Increment operators
x = 1;
y = ++x;    // x is now 2, y is also 2
y = x++;    // x is now 3, y is 2

// Decrement operators
x = 3;
y = x--;    // x is now 2, y is 3
y = --x;    // x is now 1, y is also 1
```

So, it's not so much a matter of preference as a matter of difference of results.

Comment: Sure, but the question is *why* prefix vs postfix.