# Increment order in a while loop

Tags: c++

Here I have a simple algorithm that computes the square of a number by adding up all of the odd numbers equal to the inputted number, such that:

```
1 = 1 = 1-squared
1 + 3 = 4 = 2-squared
1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = 3-squared
```

and so forth. The algorithm is as follows:

```
int triangleSquare(int number) {
    int product = 0;
    int currentOdd = 1;

    while (number--) {
        product += currentOdd;
        currentOdd += 2;
    }

    return product;
}
```

My question is about the segment:

```
while (number--) { ... }
```

For some reason I get different results between `while (--number)` and `while (number--)`, which I assume is because `--number` should decrement first before performing the while loop (and vice-versa for `number--`). My question is, why does it make a difference? Shouldn't the while loop always execute last, regardless of the increment order? I must be missing something obvious, but that seems very odd to me, almost as though `number--` makes the conditional behave like a `do {...} while()` loop.

Comment: Check this post: Your question seems similar to [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x

Comment: I understand the differences between the increments themselves. But I don't really understand why it would affect a while loop. It seems like no matter how you slice it, the increment should happen before the condition is tested, but obviously that doesn't seem to be the case. That's puzzling.

Comment: --x decrements x and returns the decremented value. x-- decrements x and returns the *original* value

Comment: `--number` is a predecrement, meaning that the value is decremented, and then the variable is retrieved, while `number--` is a postdecrement, meaning that the value is retrieved, and then the variable is decremented. So, because you are decrementing inside the while-loop's conditional, you're going to see this difference.

Comment: @sircodesalot Within the `while` loop, the value will be decremented, regardless.  But the condition in the `while` is an expression.  And the expression doesn't take into account when the actual decrementation occurs (which is unspecified), but the value of each element of the expression.  And the _value_ of `number--` is the value of `number` before the decrementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two candidate loops could be written (are equivalent to):

```
while (number-- != 0)
while (--number != 0)
```

Consider what happens when `number == 1` at loop entry:

1. The value of `number` is compared to zero and then decremented; since `1` is not `0`, the loop body is executed.
2. The value of `number` is decremented and then compared to zero; since `0` is `0`, the loop body is *not* executed.

That's the difference!

Answer (score 2):

`while (number--)` does the following:

1. evaluate `while (number)`
2. then `number--`

On the other hand `while (--number)` does this:

1. calculate `--number`
2. then evaluate `while (number)` **with the new value**

And that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible way to write code, but...

An expression has two characteristics: a return value, and side
effects.  The decrementation is the side effect; it is the same
for `--number` and `number--`.  The condition in the `while`,
however, depends on the return value; `--number` returns the
value after the decrementation; `number--` the value *before*
the decrementation.  When the decrementation actually takes
place on the variable is not really specified (for either): some
time after the preceding sequence point and before the following
one.

In other words: `--number` is the equivalent of:

```
int
decr( int& number )
{
    number -= 1;
    int results = number;
    return results;
}
```

and `number--` is the equivalent of:

```
int
decr( int& number )
{
    int results = number;
    number -= 1;
    return return;
}
```

In both cases, you're testing the return value of the function.