# Please explain output of given program.

Tags: c

the code is given below: 
it gives output true2.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int a=10;
    if(a==a--)
    printf("true 1\t");
    a=10;
    if(a==--a)
    printf("true2 \t");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The output *can't* be explained because you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read about [evaluation order and sequencing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order).

Comment: This is a pointless junk, not a code.  (Sorry). What is it expected to show?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) separate code blocks (for, if , else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ).   Compiling with the warnings enabled will produce two instances of: `warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]` One each for line 5 and line 8

Answer (score 2):

The comparison done in both of the `if` statements result in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, anything could happen. Because `a` is read and modified without an intervening sequence point. The comparison operator `==` doesn't introduce a sequence point. You probably need to learn about undefined behaviour and [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), etc to understand the problem better.

Modern compilers may also help you. For example, Clang issues:

```
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
    if(a==a--)
       ~   ^
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
    if(a==--a)
       ~  ^
```

for the two `if` statements (GCC also produces similar warnings with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`).

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not a good practice to do a-- (or --a) inside a condition, because it is not clear to read.
In order to understand the difference between a-- and --a please see the answer at: [Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

Comment: The question is about c

Comment: I know, but it is exactly the same in C and C++

Comment: That depends.  Sometimes,  pre- or postdecrement do increase also readability.  But the issue here is not the difference between pre- and postdecrement,  it is "unsequenced modification and access", as in the answer by @usr.