# Why ++ operator triggers returns a reference to a local variable warning

Tags: c++

The *main* difference between `++var` and `var++` is obvious [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x).

My question is about their impact on references. Here is the detail: I have a reference to a `cuDF::multimap` which is shown in what follows:

```
found = map->find(key)
```

When I try to increment that reference, using `++found` works fine. However, using `found++` returns this warning:

> warning: returning reference to local variable

I understand the meaning of the warning. Can someone explain why I get this warning?

**More Details**

That is, the following code snippet will generate the aforementioned warning.

```
found = map->find(key);
while (found != map->end() && found->first != unusedKey) {
    std::cout << found->second << std::endl;
    found++;
}
```

However, this doesn't produce any warning:

```
found = map->find(key);
while (found != map->end() && found->first != unusedKey) {
    std::cout << found->second << std::endl;
    ++found;
}
```

Comment: I would trust compiler that you get the warning because you are returning reference to function-local variable.

Comment: Changing `found++` to `++found` completely addresses the issue tho.

Comment: `++found` may return the reference after inc. `found++` has to return the value before inc. Hence, you probably got a copy - a temporary. Returning the reference to it makes the compiler complaint reasonable. Btw. from your exposed code, the relevant details of `found++` are not clear. A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Even though not in the accepted one, your linked question has the answer. Search for word "temporary" in browser. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1813036/5945883 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1813008/5945883

Comment: Btw. I doubt that `++found = map->find(key);` provides the intended result but `++(found = map->find(key));` might as well as `found = map->find(key); ++found;`. Just a thought...

Comment: "When I try to increment that reference" Don't tell, *show*.

Comment: What's cuDF::multimap?

Comment: @MichaelMahn it's GPU-based multimap. Here is the link if you would like to see more: https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf.

Comment: @n.m Thank you for your comment. Post updated accordingly.

Comment: @R2RT Thank you very much. That answers my question.

Comment: @all, does anyone have any idea why I got two -1 here?

Comment: @MTMD I've downvoted you, because you're asking about the behaviour of a specific class in a third party library (namespace cuDF) without providing us with any reference to it. I know that you've posted a link to the github repository now, but not even to the file with the class which gives the warning. I just don't think that we should be expected to dig through that repository and find that class if you are the one who needs help. Sorry, I don't mean that personally and just as a hint, that you should try to ask clear questions with all information in the future. I removed my downvote now.

Comment: You need to produce a [mcve], not am out-of-context fragment. Where in the world `returning reference to local variable` could possibly happen in your fragment that has no functions and no `return` statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, have dived into the source code of the library `cuDF`.

`map->find(key)` returns an iterator, which is some instantiation of the template class `cycle_iterator_adapter`.

It has its suffix increment operator defined as follow:

```cpp
__host__ __device__ cycle_iterator_adapter& operator++(int)
{
    cycle_iterator_adapter<iterator_type> old( m_begin, m_end, m_current);
    if ( m_end == (m_current+1) )
        m_current = m_begin;
    else
        ++m_current;
    return old;
}
```

Here the return type is `cycle_iterator_adapter&`, which is a reference. And since `old` is a local variable, returning it by reference generates the warning you see.

Comment: It's unfortunate when a library uses non-idiomatic code to implement fundamental pieces of their code.

Comment: @RSahu Yes. I believe it is a bug in the library. The operator should return `cycle_iterator_adapter` instead.