# PHP: What is the result of $a+++$a++

Tags: php

```
php > $a = 4;
php > echo $a+++$a++;
php > 9
```

Why is the result equal to `9` not `8` ?

`a++` will increment the value of `$a`, but return the original value that I held before being incremented. So `$a++` return `4` and `$a` return `4`, the result should be `8 = 4 + 4` ?

Answer (score 4):

The first time you get a return value from $a++ the value will be 4. But the second time it will be 5, as you already incremented it just before:

9 = 4 + 5

The final value of $a is 6, as it has been incremented twice.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, this question must reopened and the right explanation must be provided. And this question is not a duplicate of the "Pre-incrementation vs. post-incrementation" question.

Comment: I believe my explanation is correct. Here is a previous question about c/c++ that is asking something similar and notes the effect of 'use-then-change' post-incrementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x/33580329#33580329 .
There is also a comment in the php docs related to this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: As I said, you are completely wrong. Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php, example #2.

Comment: It would be useful if instead of stating "you are completely wrong" you offered some explanations as to why that might be the case. 
The example #2 in the link merely confirms my explanation
$a = 1
echo $a + $a++ will print either 2 or 3. EITHER the left $a is evaluated first: echo 1 + $a++ where $a =1 still. Thus echo 1 + 1++  which will echo 2 and then increment $a to 2. OR you evaluate the $a++ first. echo $a + ($a++)  ==> echo 2 + 1 // prints 3.
In the OP both sides will increment and so will either result in 9 = 4 + 5 OR 9 = 5 + 4. The answer is 9 regardless of the order of operation.

Comment: @user1597430 this is the correct answer. 

As stated by @dancingCamel, there are two `$a++` operators here so it doesn't matter which is evaluated first. 

The end result will be either `4 + 5` or `5 + 4`, either way the answer will be 9.

Going into more detail, the `$a++` is a "Post Increment" that will first return `$a` then increment. As a result the formula becomes `echo $a + ($a + 1)`. The first `$a++` will return the value `$a` before increment, the second `$a++` will return `$a + 1` as `$a` has been incremented once.

Comment: @Ewan, you both don't understand that `=` is also an operator that can be executed before any `++`. This is exactly what example #2 tells you in the URL above.

Comment: @user1597430 while true that is irrelevant in this example as the statement in question is `echo $a++ + $a++`. This answers why the answer is `9`.  If you have a different answer please post it with a clear explanation rather than merely posting that it is wrong with no explanation as to why.