# Can someone explain what this code means?

Tags: c++

I came across this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=5,
    b=a++ - 2;
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 3. Why is it not 4?

Comment: *the code gives the same output*. What output? The code shown does not output anything. The second expression expands to `b=a-2; a=a+1;`. Because `a++` is a post-increment which means use the value of `a` in the expression then increment it.

Comment: @web_surgeon How is the name Int defined?

Comment: I mean it gives me 6 output when i cout it in c++.

Comment: @web_surgeon And what output did you expect?

Comment: cout what? Please show the exact code as a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please check the post again! i edited it.

Comment: I just want to know what does the '-2' it gives me same output with -2 and without -2

Comment: It gives `3` with the `-2`: https://ideone.com/iSmQKS and `5` without it: https://ideone.com/ZsoWgl Your `#include <conio.h>` implies that you are using a very very very old compiler, you should use one from this millenium.

Comment: Yeah i just realized. Thank you 

Comment: This code means that you assign to `b` result of expression `a++ - 2`, you should clarify what you do not understand. How `a++` works? How `value - 2` works? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

-2 or - 2 should not give any error
see there are two types of operator post increment and pre increment
a++ is post increment it means first it will assign the value then it will increase the value by 1

meaning b = 5 - 2;
a will get get increased by 1
a=6 now but in the equation it will be 5

but if you do ++a

then it will first increase the value then assign
meaning b = 6 - 2;

-2 or - 2 wont give any error

check [here](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/406621)

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down step by step. 
These type of *comma separated expressions* happen from left to right. So its the same as this,

```cpp
int a = 5;
int b = a++ - 2;
```

In this, `a++` increments the value of `a` by one and then assigns it to it. Then the `- 2` happens. Simply what happens under the hood is,

```cpp
// Here 5 is the value of a.
int b = 5 - 2, a = a + 1;
```

More info: [Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Comment: Think you meant the right thing, but the way of explaining this can be confusing. It does NOT increment by one and then applies -2 to it. If that were the case, the result would be 4. It applies -2 to the original value (5) so we get 3. And THEN it increments "a" by one.

Comment: @AlexGeorg Yup I knew it would be a little confusing. That's why I gave a little snippet.