# React-Redux increment / decrement issue

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm doing some React-Redux practice and I've noticed a behaviour I can't understand: it works or not depending on if I use + 1 / - 1 or ++ / -- operators.

This is my reducer:

```
const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {
        counter: state.counter + 1,
      };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {
        counter: state.counter - 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and it works fine.

but if I change the increment and decrement to:

```
const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {
        counter: state.counter++,
      };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {
        counter: state.counter--,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

It will still fire the action without updating the Redux state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the second reducer you're using `prefix` operator:

```
const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {
        counter: state.counter++, //<--- prefix operator
      };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {
        counter: state.counter--, //<--- prefix operator
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**If you use the ++ operator as a prefix like:  ++var, the value of var is incremented by 1; then it returns the value.**

**If you use the ++ operator as a postfix like:  var++, the original value of var is returned first; then var is incremented by 1**.

So need to use `postfix` operator in `counterReducer` instead of `prefix` operator:

```
const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {
        counter: ++state.counter, //<--- postfix operator
      };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {
        counter: --state.counter, //<--- postfix operator
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't now the existence of postfix operators.

Comment: You're Welcome! Happy Coding :)

And as @Max suggested You should not use increment/decrement operators in redux reducers, because state is meant to be immutable.

Comment: You should never use `--state.counter` or `++state.counter` because it mutates state, best to do `state.counter = state.counter + 1`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use increment/decrement operators in redux reducers, because state is meant to be immutable. You're first example is the the preferred pattern in Redux: https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#why-is-immutability-required-by-redux

However, the reason you see that behavior is because `const y = x++` assigns the value and then increments `x`. If you want to increment and then assign the value, you would need to do `const y = ++x`.

[Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

Comment: So by using the ++ / -- operators (bothe prefix or postfix)  I will always be mutating the state and it shouldn't be done, right?

Answer (score 0):

`state.counter++` updates the value of state.counter inplace so its an action. The value at that point still remains 1.

This would work,

```cs
state.counter++;
return {
        counter: state.counter,
      };
```